# QueryDSL with blaze persistence left join sub query

Tags: java, quarkus, querydsl, blaze-persistence

I have a SQL like this

```sql
 select * from sys_region as sr 
left join 
(select count(*) as c,parent_code from sys_region * group by parent_code ) 
as c on c.parent_code = sr.parent_code
```

Also, there is entity

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@CTE
public class SysRegion extends BaseIdEntity {

  @Column(length = 128)
  private String name;

  @Column
  private Short level;

  @Column
  @ColumnDefault("0")
  private BigInteger parentCode;

 
  @Column
  @ColumnDefault("0")
  private BigInteger areaCode;

  
  @Column
  private String cityCode;

  @Column
  private Integer zipCode;

  @Column
  @ColumnDefault("0.0")
  private BigDecimal lng;
  
  @Column
  @ColumnDefault("0.0")
  private BigDecimal lat;

  @Column
  private String shortName;

  @Column
  private String mergerName;
}
```

And I am using quarkus with queryDSL and Blaze persistence

How to implement SQL query using that mapping to my entity?

And I saw [this link](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/core/manual/en_US/index.html#querydsl-features)

Do not have full example for this case `left join with sub query and mapping to entity`?